# Pathfinder doesn't work smoothly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, shapes

I am applying pathfinder- minus front to cut out some shape. Then I notice the common border the shapes share are more bold/thick than rest lines/borders.

At first  I thought am doing something wrong, Then I activated outline mode, zoomed 64000% and then I notice lines are not placed on each other accurately! Common lines are slightly away from each other and very tiny gaps are between lines.

pathfinder-minus front should place common lines above each other with 100% accuracy, right? and doesn't make the common lines bold/thick -that was my understanding. Or am wrong?

I dnt want this to happen. am worried what if it is visible if my client prints it?

Any solution?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 100% accuracy is sadly not possible. Vector does have a "resolution" of sorts because of limited decimals. Often it's best to overlap shapes instead of cutting them out. There are a few questions on the site about this issue. I don't have time to find them right now.

Comment: Thank you Wolff

Comment: The bolding isnt because of the line imprecision but conflation. You can indeed fix this error. All you need to do is insert a point in the other object too. This will make the math work out. You will nolonger have "tearing", which is the technical name of this. In either case you really really dont want to do this. Why well because of another technical issue in antialiasation called conflation artefacts. So it turns out that nearly all vector engines work wrong. So since overlapping is easier, includes less data and avoids conflation artefacts you should really really let the objects overlap.

Comment: @joojaa Wow. That is really helpful. I can google and sort things out now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way Illustrator works with the limitations it has, but if you need to zoom in 64000% to see this in outline mode, you are guaranteed ***100% definitely sure your client will not see this on print***.

Comment: haha. Okay. Yeah Client wont zoom  in that much. I am scrupulous.